# Android: Forcestop on my Lenovo API 23 device disables Broadcasts - is there a way to work around this?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, broadcast

i have Broadcasts set up via AlarmManager and they are registered in the Manifest, so they can run even if the App is not running.
On my API 26 Emulator everything works fine, not matter if i close the App in the TaskManager or not. However, on my Lenovo Tablet with API 23, the Alarms are not working, after i closed the App in the TaskManager. If i just close the App, it keeps working, even the ON_BOOT receiver keeps working after restarting the device.

Is there any workaround for this or is that just something i have to accept on certain devices?

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.